# How to solve this SAT question quickly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this question in a SAT practice:

---

$\frac{n^2+1}{-2n+8}=-13$

What is the greater of the two values of $n$ that satisfy the equation above?

Of course we can solve the quadratic equation, but I think it should be a way to solve it quicker using some number theory. I tried but I thought more confusing. Someone have a simpler idea how to tackle this question (using number theory or not)?

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite the thing as $\frac{n^2 +1}{n-4} = 26$ ?

Comment: It could be of great help if you put up your own attempt alongside the question. Thank you.

Comment: How is solving the quadratic not quick? It is like two lines. $n^2 -26n +105=0\implies (n-21)(n-5)=0$.

Comment: Yes.... you have the quadratic formula with you, right ?

Comment: Well, if you wanna try guessing, there's a way.

Comment: Just find the values of $n$ for which the numerator or denomiantor becomes $0$ can be considered the constraints between or around which the required value is present.

Comment: Generally you have 30 to 40 seconds to solve a question in the SAT test. The part is from the no calculator section.

Comment: For instance, $n = 4$ will make the denominator $0$ and $n = i$ will make the numerator $0$.

Comment: "Generally you have 30 to 40 seconds to solve a question in the SAT test. The part is from the no calculator section." - I understand that as a 10-th grader.

Comment: No idea what spectre is banging on about. It would be interesting if there was a number theory method by I cannot imagine it being quicker. It would not take me more than 30 seconds to factorise that.

Comment: I am not banging on something but trying to help him guess. But of course , my guesswork will be ineffective if the options are from the supposed interval that we may try to make through the guesswork.....

Comment: And hence, we end up with the answer that there's no quicker way than the use of a quadratic equation.

Comment: I think, the main problem is the time pressure. Maybe, the exercises are easy enough to be calculated within the time limit, but it is not easy to calculate the solutions both quickly and accurate. But better trying that than wasting time (you do not have anyway) to guess the solution with another method, even if it would be quicker. Unless you were told such a quicker method, assuming it exists at all.

Comment: Many people here will think that the task is easy , but it starts with the transform, you have to do correctly and then you have to determine the solutions which is easier with an "eye for the solutions", but if someone does not have this, he has to use the formula for the quadratic equation. I would not consider $30$ seconds to be much time for one such exercise.

Comment: @Peter I do not see why quadratic formula would be required. If you know that $n^2-26n+105=0$ then the only task is to see what factors of $105$ can add or subtract to $26$ (It would not take long to discard $(1,105)$ and $(3,35)$ before arriving at $(5,21)$). From then it is just choosing the correct signs. It is not guess work, or "an eye for the solutions" - it is methodical. I would be shocked if an adept maths student took longer than $60$ seconds to complete that process (transforming it included).

Comment: The point is however that the only problem is the time since apparently the author has no problem to solve the exercises in principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the quadratic formula and you do not even need to write down the quadratic equation completely. The equation is equivalent to $n^2-26n+<something>=0$. So by Vieta, the sum  of the roots is 26. One of the roots is clearly 5 because $5^2+1=26$ and $-2*5+8=-2$. So the other root must be 21.
The answer: 21.

Comment: I would argue that is more complicated than writing it all out, which only has the extra step of $8\cdot 13+1$. Simply noticing that $5$ solves both those equations is harder than testing which factors of $105$ add to $26$.

Comment: @tomasliam:   The discussion was whether one needs the quadratic formula. My answer and your comment say "no". The  answer to  what is easier: to write down the equation or to guess a root, depends on who is solving the problem, For me what I wrote is easier. I do not know what is easier for you or for the OP. I know people who would  prefer using the quadratic formula.